# How to clear/empty dojo widgits

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have an application which hides the Dojo elements on the Form such as (Text field , Radio Button , Combo Box etc) on a certain event. It uses element.style.display = "none" to hide the widgets in a loop. However I am unable to clear the contents of the elements on the Form to initial state (null or empty etc). Hence, the values end up in Database when they should be empty.

```
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) 
{
    if (ids[i].length > 0) 
    {
        dojo.query("div[id*=" + ids[i] + "]", form).forEach(function(element)                      
        element.style.display = "none";     
        // HOW TO CLEAR THE CONTENTS AS WELL ?       
    })
}
```

Please note since there are all kinds of elements such as text boxes and comboboxes etc so I can not hard code something like element.lastChild = "" etc because it only works for text boxes.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set the values of those elements to blank string?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to put all the form dijits inside a `dijit/form/Form` and whenever you want to reset them, just call the `reset` function from the form.

Take a look on this link for the basic implementation of a form: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Form.html

You can also override the form `onReset` function, in case you need a custom reset for your form. Additionally, you can override the form dijits `reset` function too, since when `Form.reset()` is called, it will look for all the children dijits and call their `reset` function individually. That might be useful in situations where only a few dijits `reset` shouldn't be handled in the default way.